# panda-melt is not transposing columns into a sequance

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-melt

I read a csv it has multiples columns. I want to transpose

```
Date                A        B            C
   25/5/2019       25      765.3        896
   26/5/2019       98                  769 
   27/5/2019      27.6    453.2       98.6
```

I have tried

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['DateTime'],value_vars=['A','B','C'],
                  var_name='detail',value_name='')
df2 = df2.sort_values(['DateTime'])
```

it is changing columns into rows but  I am having two problems.

1. it is also adding column name along with the value which I does not want. I just need values
2. there is no order of columns. I want to transpose col in a sequence.

Current output is

```
Date            final values        
 25/5/2019      A 25                
 25/5/2019      C 896                    
 25/5/2019       B 765.3                  
 26/5/2019       B                    
 26/5/2019       A 253  
 26/5/2019       C 769  
 27/5/2019       C 506
```

I want to transpose col in a sequence always start with A then B and then C. Expected output is.

```
Date            final values        
 25/5/2019       25                
 25/5/2019       765.3                    
 25/5/2019       896                   
 26/5/2019       98                    
 26/5/2019       null 
 26/5/2019       769
 27/5//2019      203
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

> An additional point
> I have now required output column final value. I need to assign that each value belongs to which column for this I have code for three columns. for example A=100, B=200, C=100. Is there any way that I can print codes next to each columns value

```html
Date            final values    code       
 25/5/2019       25              100  
 25/5/2019       765.3           200         
 25/5/2019       896             300      
 26/5/2019       98              100      
 26/5/2019       null            200
 26/5/2019       769              300
 27/5//2019      203             100
```

Comment: If you have extra columns, update your post with them, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An hybrid version of the two previous answers with `melt`. You just have to transpose your dataframe before `melt` to keep your values ordered:

```
out = (
    df.set_index('Date').T.melt(value_name='final value', ignore_index=False) \
      .assign(code=lambda x: x.index.map({'A': 100, 'B': 200, 'C': 300}))
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(out)

# Output
        Date final value  code
0  25/5/2019        25.0   100
1  25/5/2019       765.3   200
2  25/5/2019       896.0   300
3  26/5/2019        98.0   100
4  26/5/2019         NaN   200
5  26/5/2019       769.0   300
6  27/5/2019        27.6   100
7  27/5/2019       453.2   200
8  27/5/2019        98.6   300
```

Comment: I updated my answer. can you check it please?

Comment: it throws following error       TypeError: melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'

Comment: You have a version of Pandas prior to 1.1.0. You really need to upgrade it.

Comment: Thankyou for the ans. I updated the version. now error has gone. Every thing works.

Comment: What do you mean? `out` is already a dataframe

Comment: no, every thing works.  higly recommended Ans  but after editing question I got new suggetion which exactly match with required result.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative solution with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and removeinf second level from columns names by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('DateTime')[['A','B','C']]
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index(name='final values'))
print (df)
    DateTime  final values
0  25/5/2019          25.0
1  25/5/2019         765.3
2  25/5/2019         896.0
3  26/5/2019          98.0
4  26/5/2019           NaN
5  26/5/2019         769.0
6  27/5/2019          27.6
7  27/5/2019         453.2
8  27/5/2019          98.6
```

Comment: it is printing ok but  it is also transposing 2 columns (date, Time ) which I don't require. how to avoid them?

Comment: @Katja - add filtering `A,B,C` - answer was edited.

Comment: @it throws following error KeyError: "None of ['DateTime'] are in the columns"

Comment: @Katja change `Date` to `DateTime`

Comment: @Katja - some problem with solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the underlying array for a flexible reshaping:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': df['Date'].repeat(df.shape[1]-1),
              'final values': df.set_index('Date').to_numpy().ravel()})
```

or:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': df['Date'].repeat(df.shape[1]-1),
              'final values': df[['A', 'B', 'C']].to_numpy().ravel()})
```

output:

```
        Date final values
0  25/5/2019         25.0
0  25/5/2019        765.3
0  25/5/2019        896.0
1  26/5/2019         98.0
1  26/5/2019          NaN
1  26/5/2019        769.0
2  27/5/2019         27.6
2  27/5/2019        453.2
2  27/5/2019         98.6
```